# SPFX with function app backend CORS restrictions when using AAD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, cors, azure-functions, spfx

I have a backend with some azure functions, and due to some new frontend using the same backend, I am now having trouble accessing the app due to cors restrictions.

Below are images of the settings in azure.

[Azure Function CORS settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HNNe.png)

[Azure auth classic settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukfhM.png)

[Advance auth classic settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRZv4.png)

Code which calls the backend

```
        let test = await this._context.aadTokenProviderFactory.getTokenProvider();
        let token = await test.getToken(this.baseUrl, true);
        let data = await fetch(`${this.baseUrl}/api/v1.1/search`, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Accept: 'application/json'
            },
            method: 'GET',
        });
```

***Access to fetch at somename-api.azurewebsites.net/api/v1.1/search/workplaces' from origin 'https://somename.sharepoint.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.***

My issue is that if I try to call the endpoint (AZURE FUNCTION GET) from the browser I get the cors error pasted above.

However, if I try to access the endpoint on postman (without token) i get a 401, which is as expected, and if I use the token I get a response.

[App registration urls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3TcJ.png)

Does anybody have an idea on whats going on?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Postman automatically adds the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`  header to a request. You will need to add the header in the code. Please see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) for the documentation.